# Generic QoS Message batching and compression in Java

Tags: java, networking, messaging, qos, batching

We have a custom messaging system written in Java, and I want to implement a basic batching/compression feature that basically under heavy load it will aggregate a bunch of push responses into a single  push response.

Essentially:

- if we detect 3 messages were sent in the past second then start batching responses and schedule a timer to fire in 5 seconds
- The timer will aggregate all the message responses received in the next 5 seconds into a single message

I'm sure this has been implemented before I'm just looking for the best example of it in Java. I'm not looking for a full blown messaging layer, just the basic detect messages per second and schedule some task (obviously I can easily write this myself I just want to compare it with any existing algorithms to make sure I'm not missing any edge cases or that I've simplified the problem as much as possible).

Are there any good open source examples of building a basic QoS batching/throttling/compression implementations?

Answer (score 0):

we are using a very similar mechanism for high load.

it will work as you described it
* Aggregate messages over a given interval
* Send a List instead of a single message after that.
* Start aggregating again.

You should watch out for the following pitfalls:
* If you are using a transacted messaging system like JMS you can get into trouble because your implementation will not be able to send inside the JMS transaction so it will keep aggregating. Depending on the size of your data structure to hold the messages this can run out of space. If you are have very long transactions sending many messages this can pose a problem. 
* Sending a message in such a way will happen asynchronous because a different thread will be sending the message and the thread calling the send() method will only put it in the data structure.
* Sticking to the JMS example you should keep in mind that they way messages are consumed is also changed by this approach. Because you will receive the list of messages from JMS as a single message. So once you commit this single JMS message you commited the entire list of messages. You should check if this i a problem to your requirements.